# customtkinter - How to edit CTkEntry border?

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, customtkinter

So I'm using the customtkinter to create an interface. I have an entry and I want it to have a background, but I cant't do it. In the documentation, there isn't an argument for the border. Specifically, I want to change the width and the color. Does anyone know how I can do it?

```
from tkinter import mainloop
import customtkinter as ctk

root = ctk.CTk()
root.geometry("200x200")

e = ctk.CTkEntry(master=root,
  text_color="green",
  font=("tahoma", 20),
  # borderwidth=5,
  # bd=5,
)
e.insert(0, "text goes here...")
e.pack()

mainloop()
```

Here `bd` throws an error. `borderwidth` works but not as expected. Maybe you can't just edit the border in the CTkEntry widget. But I don't know.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, if you don't know what a CTkEntry widget can do and what it can't, why are you using it?  Tkinter has been around for a long time and is extensively documented.  The tkinter Entry widget has all the features you need.

Comment: First of all, I wanted a more modern GUI, than the original tkinter library and I found about customtkinter. Which actually give you some more options, like dark theme and corner radius. That's why I'm using it.

Comment: Also the width and height attributes are in pixels and not in screen units, which I think is more convenient.

Comment: No you cannot because the round corner box is actually a group of `Canvas` items.

Comment: A border for the CTkEntry isn't implemented yet, but maybe I will add it in a future release.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The CTkEntry widget now has a border as of version 3.0. You can upgrade customtkinter like this:

`pip3 install customtkinter --upgrade`

To edit the border you can pass the `border_width` option and `border_color` option:

```py
import tkinter
import customtkinter

root_tk = customtkinter.CTk()
root_tk.geometry("400x340")

entry = customtkinter.CTkEntry(root_tk, border_width=2, border_color="gray50")
entry.pack(pady=y_padding, padx=10, pady=20)

root_tk.mainloop()
```

Documentation: https://customtkinter.tomschimansky.com/documentation/

Answer (score 0):

CUSTOMTKINTER
For border there isn't a syntax but you can make a border using border_width="" and for coloring your border you can use border_color=""

to add background color for you entry use bg_color=""
FOR SOME USERS u may find your corner radius is showing like it's corner is having a leftover of a square like it's corners are being build out of normal tkinter entry(usually found when you have a background image) for that use bg_color and fg_color inside the entry to blend it

in your code you don't have to type insert externally for temporary text, in customtkinter you can use placeholder_text="" INSIDE ENTRY, it will automatically delete that text when clicked and pops back when focus is out, to change color of that text use placeholder_text_color=""